# Alt+Enter not accepting IntelliJ suggestions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enter, intellij-14, alt-key

After I typed **"@Test"** (without the quotes) and then hit <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>, IntelliJ suggested adding the `"import org.junit.Test;"` statement by pressing <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.

However, every time I tried to do this, IntelliJ presented me with a **"Generate"** menu instead of adding the suggested import statement.

In the past, I've successfully used <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> in IntelliJ 13 on my Windows 7 Professional workstation at work.

Currently, I am having the problem with <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> not working on a brand-new installation of IntelliJ 14 that I have running on Windows 7 Professional via Bootcamp on my MacBook Pro. I have left the Bootcamp keyboard settings at their defaults. So <kbd>**fn**</kbd>+option is equivalent to <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>, and works fine in other programs.

Therefore, <kbd>**fn**</kbd> + option(<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>) + <kbd>**enter**</kbd> should work in IntelliJ to accept a suggestion.

However, as described above, this is not the case on my system. Does anyone have any ideas for how to fix this?

UPDATE: @Danny provided the solution: On a MacBook Pro running IntelliJ IDEA 14 on Windows 7 via Bootcamp, press <kbd>**option**</kbd> + <kbd>**enter**</kbd> (without the <kbd>**fn**</kbd>) for the equivalent behavior of pressing <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> on traditional PCs.

This works to accept IntelliJ suggestions such as adding import statements to your code needed by dependencies.

Comment: Option+enter (without fn) works on osx installations of IntelliJ.  Maybe it will work on your version running Bootcamp?

Comment: Danny's suggestion worked for me, also running Idea 14 bootcamped on a MBP (Windows 8.1, however).

Comment: @Danny, your solution of pressing option+enter (without fn) worked on my system. I have updated my original post to describe your solution.

Comment: Yes, I run into similar issues when as I regularly switch back and forth between Windows OS, Ubuntu, and OSX.  I have gotten used to trying one or the other until it works :( - wishing it was consistent behaviour in all environments/OS but that's another topic :)

Comment: As an aid, you can refer to the key mapping for OSX https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

Comment: @DannyDaglas - I am on win 7, 64 bit with Intellij Idea 2016.2.4. Alt enter has stopped working properly. It does not offer any suggestions when I want to create a test case in junit. Can you please advise how to fix this ?